# Number of odd function over symmetric interval.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $ A = \left \{ -2,-1,0,1,2 \right \} $

How many $ f : A \rightarrow  A $ odd functions exist?

How am I supposed to approach these type of problems? The graphic representation doesn't seem to help at all.

Comment: Choose the value of $f(0)$.  Choose the value of $f(1)$, noting that whatever choice is made here must also be the result of $f(-1)$ as per the requirement $f$ be odd.  Choose the value of $f(2)$, noting that whatever choice is made here must also be the result of $f(-2)$ as per the requirement $f$ be odd.  Apply [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and conclude.

Comment: @JMoravitz: There's no free choice for the value of $f(0)$, since it has to be $0$ for an odd function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Since we're dealing with odd functions here, this is the same thing as asking how many functions there are from $\{0,1,2\}$ into $A$ such that $f(0)=0$. And this is the same thing as asking how many functions there are from $\{1,2\}$ into $A$.

Comment: You have a free choice for $f(0)$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I fully agree!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: So the right answer is $ 25 $. Thanks